# Unable to use fully qualified table name in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to update a table on several remote servers by iterating over a list of server names and executing some dynamic SQL. See below.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Server_Name VARCHAR(25)
SET @Server_Name='SomeServer'

SET @Sql='UPDATE ' + @Server_Name + '.dba_sandbox.dbo.SomeTable SET SomeCol=''data'''
PRINT @Sql
EXEC @Sql
```

Which produces the following output:

```
UPDATE SomeServer.dba_sandbox.dbo.SomeTable SET SomeCol='data'
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 7
Could not find server 'UPDATE SomeServer' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers.
```

Now SomeServer is a linked server. If I execute the printed out SQL statement it works fine. Note also, in the error message, it thinks the remote server is 'UPDATE SomeServer', rather than 'SomeServer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using parantheses:

```
EXEC(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried brackets?

`[SomeServer].[dba_sandbox].[dbo].[SomeTable]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing it but have you tried creating the update in this form:

update a
set somecol = 'data'
from someserver.dba_sandbox.dbo.SomeTable a

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using

```
EXEC @Sql
```

Not

```
Exec(@sql)
```